# Can't claim EOS tokens. Problem with GAS amount when claim EOS tokens

Tags: contract-deployment, myetherwallet, out-of-gas, gas-limit, gas-refund

To make story short,I participated in 167 EOS distribution period, so i've sent ETH amount to their account 0xd0a6E6C54DbC68Db5db3A091B171A77407Ff7ccf. Then i've registered my public EOS key and right after 167 distribution period ended i tried to claim tokens as it described here https://prnt.sc/hkuko6

Claim EOS Tokens

Select claimAll.

Unlock your Wallet

Amount to Send: 0

Gas Limit: at least 90000

But i have error every time, it says:

Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas].

Here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/hkvb1z.
I had this error a few times, despite the fact that suggested gas amount should be at least 90 000. Also i've spent 15$ equivalent to ethereum with no result. Does anybody know where the problem is?

Comment: Constantine, i've got the same problem. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: how did you figure out what was your period (i.e. day) for the claim?
Also could you please say how much gas did you use for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I had success when i claimed tokens for one period not for claimAll, as it was advised.

Answer (score 0):

They messed this up badly in my opinion. It's a complicated mess to claim coins. Why? No other coin has this problem. You pay and it's sent.
Color me NOT impressed with this money sponge. But hey, they got really, really rich off it, so good for them.